# How do i show the nested JSON data in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a `JSON` data as

```
{
    "data1": "val1",
    "data2": val2,
    "data3": [{
      "data4": "val3",
      "data5": "val4"
    }, {
      "data6": "val5",
      "data7": "val6"
    }],
    "data8": [{
      "data9": "val7",
      "data10": "val8",
      "data11": "val9"
    }, {
      "data12": "val10",
      "data14": "val11",
      "data14": "val12"
    }, {
      "data15": "val13",
      "data16": "val14",
      "data17": "val15"
    }],
    "id": 1
}
```

I want to keep the inner `JSON` as multiple select check-boxes or multiple select drop-down in a cell.

For ex: for `data3` column a single cell will have a multiple select check-boxes or multiple select drop-down with values of `data4` and `data6` in 1 set and in another set `data5` and `data7`.

How do i represent the data here? Any better solution also in appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how I do the same. The gridOptions is populated in the controller. In this case I use http://ui-grid.info/

Please note that the code must be refactored because it is ugly, however, it is working fine.

```
vm.gridOptions =
            {
                columnDefs: [
                    { name: 'id', field: 'id' },
                    { name: 'name', field: 'name' },
                    { name: 'route', field: 'route' },
                    { name: 'sysmodulescreen name', field: 'sysModuleId' },
                    {
                        name: 'enable/disable',
                        field: 'isEnabled',
                        cellTemplate: '<button ' +
                            'ng-if="row.entity.isEnabled == 1" ' +
                            'class="btn btn-danger" ' +
                            'ng-model="row.entity.id" ' +
                            'ng-click="grid.appScope.disableModuleScreen(row.entity.id)">Disable</button>' +
                            '<button ' +
                            'ng-if="row.entity.isEnabled == 0" ' +
                            'class="btn btn-success" ' +
                            'ng-model="row.entity.id" ' +
                            'ng-click="grid.appScope.enableModuleScreen(row.entity.id)">Enable&nbsp;</button>'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'edit',
                        field: 'id',
                        cellTemplate: '<button class="btn" ng-model="row.entity.id" ng-click="grid.appScope.editModuleScreen(row.entity.id)">Edit</button>'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'delete',
                        field: 'id',
                        cellTemplate: '<button class="btn" ng-model="row.entity.id" ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteModuleScreen(row.entity.id)">Delete</button>'
                    }
                ]
            };
```